# Make goroutines stay running after returning from function

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, go

in Java I can make threads run for long periods of time and I don't need to stay within the function that started the thread.

Goroutines, Go's answer to Threads seem to stop running after I return from the function that started the routine.

How can I make these routines stay running and return from the calling function?

Thanks

Comment: If it returned from the called function, what would the goroutine be running?

Comment: I want it to send a UDP broadcast message over the network for a predefined amount of time, while doing other things.

Comment: Goroutines do continue running after you return from the function that called the goroutine (see my answer). What makes you think they don't do this?

Comment: Goroutines have a lifecycle like Java's Daemon threads.  They don't stop the app from exiting but they do run as long as the their initial function doesn't exit (Runnable.run in java's case, or whatever function you called with "go" in go's case)

Comment: I think the confusion is that most of the examples of `go` routines are launched from `main` (for example, https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1 . If the final `time.Sleep` is removed, the program doesn't work).  As long as `main` is still running, the go routines will run to completion.

Answer (score 27):

Goroutines *do* continue running after the function that invokes them exits: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xusa-cwcZJ)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func countToTen() chan bool {
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
        done <- true
    }()
    return done
}

func main() {
    done := countToTen()
    fmt.Println("countToTen() exited")

    // reading from the 'done' channel will block the main thread
    // until there is something to read, which won't happen until
    // countToTen()'s goroutine is finished
    <-done
}
```

Note that we need to block the main thread until `countToTen()`'s goroutine completes. If we don't do this, the main thread will exit and all other goroutines will be stopped even if they haven't completed their task yet.

Comment: Just not after the main function. Exiting the main function quits all threads and goroutines.

Comment: Isn't it wrong to say we have exited from the `countToTen` function. That function is still asynchronously running in background.

Comment: `countToTen` isn't running in the background, but it spawned another goroutine which *is* running in the background.

Answer (score 6):

You can.

If you want to have a `go-routine` running in background forever, you need to have some kind of infinite loop, with some kind of graceful stopping mechanism in place, usually via channel. And invoke the `go-routine` via some other function, so even after this other function terminates, your `go-routine` will still be running.

For example:

```
// Go routine which will run indefinitely.
// Unless you send a signal on quit channel.
func goroutine(quit chan bool) {
   for {
      select {
         case <-quit:
           fmt.Println("quit")
           return
         default:
           fmt.Println("Do your thing")
      }
   }
}

// Go routine will still be running, 
// after you return from this function.
func invoker() {
     q := make(chan bool)
     go goroutine(q)
}
```

Here, you can call `invoker`, when you want to start the `go-routine`. And even after `invoker` returns, your go-routine will still be running in background.

Only exception to this is, when `main` function returns all `go-routines` in the application will be terminated.